# MySQL Join with conditions on join on the fly

Tags: mysql

I need to know, how do i do this on the fly,

for example i have customers who are in the each different duedate statuses, i want to select MAX (most recent due date) ON LEFT JOIN  currently when its join two tables it selects the oldest duedate which is not what i want..

```
SELECT c.customerid, i.datedue
                        FROM  customers c
                               LEFT JOIN invoice i 
                                 ON i.customerid = c.customerid
                        WHERE  i.datedue <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
                               AND c.status!='d'
                        GROUP  BY i.customerid
                        ORDER BY i.datedue DESC
                        LIMIT  0, 1000
```

Comment: It looks as though you're trying to build a list of customers (by ID), along with their most recently missed invoice (if any, again by ID) - restricted to the top 1000 invoices? Is that correct?

Comment: You should also save your due date as type datetime or date, since 32-bit unix timestamps only have a 68 year time span and since you can perform other date functions faster when the timestamp is in native SQL.  For instance, you would change the above to `WHERE i.datedue <= NOW()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the max() function:

```
SELECT c.customerid, MAX(i.datedue)
FROM customers c LEFT JOIN invoice i ON i.customerid = c.customerid
WHERE i.datedue <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() and c.status!='d'
GROUP BY i.customerid
ORDER BY i.datedue DESC
LIMIT 0,1000
```

This will give you the maximum datedue for each customer.

Comment: +1 for keeping it simple and using the often forgotten `GROUP BY`